# Visual Studio v2003, v2005, v2008 and v2010 existing on the same system

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I currently have Visual Studio v2003, v2005, v2008 installed on my system. Things work fine...no issues.

I now have to install Visual Studio 2010 on my system and just wanted to know if anyone has a setup like mine or knows if there are any potential issues with so many versions existing on a system.

Really don't have a choice to remove older versions as we have a lot of legacy products written in these old versions and we are not upgrading them to new versions, only doing bug fixes on them.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

VS2010 supports targeting on multiple versions of .NET Framework (i.e. 2.0 or later), which mean it is designed to support the projects that were built with VS2005/VS2008 so-called backward-compatibility.

So I think no conflict here between these versions,

I've found a nice Myths and facts about VS 2005/2008/2010, check out this link here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ee679805.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It should work.

I have vs2003, vs2008 and vs2010 installed and I see no issue (but vs2010 is not yet used for production code).

M.

Answer (score 0):

All these versions of Visual Studio are independent.

You should have no problem (other than lack of disk space!) installing VS2010 as well.

Just make sure you install the service pack as well.

Answer (score 0):

They cohabitate fine, I have a similar setup myself.

You should at least push for migrating away from 2003 and 2005 though, they use some pretty old technology, and pretty much everyone these days has .net 3.5 on their systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use VS 2010 I would highly recommend you do for all new projects - even if you have to target an earlier version of .NET framework.

Keep the old versions of VS installed only for maintenance of projects that cannot be migrated to VS 2010 version.

By the way, the migration to VS 2010 is often very trivial and well worth an hour or two of effort!